# Column Editing is Disabled. How to Enable?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench, in order to design an ERD (Entity Relation Diagram).

I can make use of indexes, triggers, etc. but for some reason the *columns tab*, which allows me to add data or just edit the tables is *disabled*. I have searched online without success. Any ideas on how to enable it?

I would like to be able to add data into my tables, which I cannot now do, since the process is disabled.

Comment: Columns tab? Is this a problem with MySQL Workbench or some other tool?

Comment: As @ypercubeᵀᴹ says, could you please name the tool that you are using. Tool questions are not off-topic here, but it **does** help to know which particular one we are dealing with.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is MySQL workbench.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Sorry, I just edited, it is Workbench.

Comment: @Vérace: Sorry, please see my edit.